# How to convert image provider to image in flutter inorder use in canvas?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make image object in flutter in order to use that image object in canvas `drawImageRect(..)`.

`var image = Image.asset('assets/filename.png');` This don't work. So, how to make this image object inorder to pass image object in the drawImageRect(..) method.

```dart
Canvas canvas2 = Canvas(recorder);
Paint paint2 = new Paint();
canvas2.drawImageRect(image, source, dest, paint2); // unable to make this image object
```

Comment: read [ImageProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) official docs

Comment: but if you have your image in  your local file system [decodeImageFromList()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/decodeImageFromList.html) would be much easier